# JQuery each not working but by element does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where the first line is working but the each part isn't. There's no syntax errors so I'm at a loss what isn't working.

```
function met() {
    $("select[id*='outcome']")[0].selectedIndex = 2; # this works
        $("select[id*='outcome']").each(function() {
            $(this).selectedIndex = 2; # this doesn't
     });
}
```

Comment: No syntax errors, but there should be a runtime error in the console. Try `this.selectedIndex = 2;`

Comment: I meant runtime error sorry, and no such error in the console strangely. Anyway, that fixed it so no matter! Thanks

Comment: because jQuery object does not have selected index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because with this you are setting selectedIndex on the jQuery object

```
$(this).selectedIndex = 2;
```

needs to be

```
 $(this).prop("selectedIndex", 2);
```

or

```
this.selectedIndex = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery object does not have selected index, try:

```
$("select[id*='outcome']").each(function() {
        $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 2);
});
```

Comment: It's `prop()` in that regard only, `selectedIndex` is a prototype property of the accordant element defined as `HTMLSelectElement.prototype.selectedIndex`